# How long does it take to complete the campaign registration of Twillio

Tags: twilio, sms

I'm using Twillio for sending SMS, and recently my messages are being blocked by twillio because the number wasn't registered. I registered a twillio campaign to associate my 10DLC numbers with the connected Messaging Service as instructed by twillio, but 2 weeks has passed by without any updates.

Getting stressed and frustrated. Can you help me to get this faster?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got approved. Took about 2 weeks. Also, if you use company info, like EIN, it will be faster than applying for individual.